# Font rendering between IE8 and IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

Starting with IE9, the font on my site navigation text is now thinner due to the difference in how IE9 renders my font. What changed in IE9 that is causing this and is there any way to tweak or change it? This picture is the after(top, IE9) and the before(bottom, IE8).

[image]

Comment: Had my description backwards. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized the issue. There is a new font engine being used in IE9 that has different font spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional IE hacks in css to define font size and spacing 
Something like

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

Welcome to the MS hell :)

Comment: Ha. Not using any IE conditionals yet and don't want to ever start. =)